How to Set the Path for `~` in PowerShell
I have a PowerShell session where I defined the following environment variables:

HOMEPATH.
USERPROFILE.

I set both to the same value.
For instance, D:\User.
I expect, when I run cd ~ in the same session to change the directory to D:\User.
Yet, it still uses the original: C:\User\<MyUserName>.
What should be changed so cd ~ will respect the environment variables?

Related: Is there a way to override ~ (tilde) location in powershell
